# How to escape the equals sign in properties files

Tags: java, properties, escaping

How can I escape the equals sign (`=`) in Java property files? I would like to put something as the following in my file:

```
table.whereclause=where id=100
```

Answer (score 118, accepted):

In your specific example you don't need to escape the equals - you only need to escape it if it's part of the key.  The properties file format will treat all characters after the first unescaped equals as part of the value.

Comment: don't know why this has not been marked up ! Simplest correct answer ! And most of the times people are looking for escaping value in properties file !

Comment: Small correction: will treat as value all characters after the first unescaped equals and trailing spaces, that is, leading spaces *in the value* are taken out. Example "myKey=my value" is the same as "myKey = my value".

Answer (score 92):

Moreover, Please refer to [**load(Reader reader)** method from `Property` class on javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader))

In `load(Reader reader)` method documentation it says

> The key contains all of the characters
> in the line starting with the first
> non-white space character and up to,
> but not including, the first unescaped
> `'='`, `':'`, or white space character
> other than a line terminator. All of
> these key termination characters may
> be included in the key by escaping
> them with a preceding backslash
> character; for example,
>
> ```
> \:\=
> ```
>
> would be the two-character key `":=".`
> Line terminator characters can be
> included using `\r` and `\n` escape
> sequences. Any white space after the
> key is skipped; if the first non-white
> space character after the key is `'='`
> or `':'`, then it is ignored and any
> white space characters after it are
> also skipped. All remaining characters
> on the line become part of the
> associated element string; if there
> are no remaining characters, the
> element is the empty string `""`. Once
> the raw character sequences
> constituting the key and element are
> identified, escape processing is
> performed as described above.

Answer (score 27):

Default escape character in Java is '\'. 
However, Java properties file has format key=value, it should be considering everything after the first equal as value.

Comment: except leading whitespace (oh and the '=' between key and value isn't required, it could be : or a blank space)

Comment: is there any way to read '\' from properties file ?  (my)Java application used to read the password from properties file which is contains special character's .  Example : \s9JPT,IS59j=EMS  , when i am reading this value from properties file i am getting only - s9JPT,IS59j=EMS - which is not correct .

Comment: @Vasanth In that case, you have to escape the backslash ( `\\s9JPT,IS59j=EMS` ).

Answer (score 21):

The best way to avoid this kind of issues it to build properties programmatically and then store them. For example, using code like this:

```
java.util.Properties props = new java.util.Properties();
props.setProperty("table.whereclause", "where id=100");
props.store(System.out, null);
```

This would output to System.out the properly escaped version.

In my case the output was:

```
#Mon Aug 12 13:50:56 EEST 2013
table.whereclause=where id\=100
```

As you can see, this is an easy way to generate content of .properties files that's guaranteed to be correct. And you can put as many properties as you want.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, two leading  '\\' working fine for me.

For example : 
if your word contains the '#' character (e.g. aa#100, you can escape it with two
leading '\\'

```html
   key= aa\\#100
```

Comment: I second that, you need two backslashes (glassfish 4.1, build 13)

Answer (score 2):

You can look here [Can the key in a Java property include a blank character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108103/java-properties-is-there-a-way-a-key-can-include-a-blank-character)

for escape equal '=' \u003d

table.whereclause=where id=100

key:[table.whereclause] value:[where id=100]

table.whereclause\u003dwhere id=100

key:[table.whereclause=where] value:[id=100]

table.whereclause\u003dwhere\u0020id\u003d100

key:[table.whereclause=where id=100] value:[]

Answer (score 2):

In Spring or Spring boot application.properties file here is the way to escape the special characters;

table.whereclause=where id'\='100

Answer (score 1):

This method should help to programmatically generate values guaranteed to be 100% compatible with `.properties` files:

```
public static String escapePropertyValue(final String value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return null;
    }

    try (final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()) {
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("escaped", value);
        properties.store(writer, null);
        writer.flush();

        final String stringifiedProperties = writer.toString();
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)escaped=(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(System.lineSeparator()) + "*");
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(stringifiedProperties);

        if (matcher.find() && matcher.groupCount() <= 2) {
            return matcher.group(matcher.groupCount());
        }

        // This should never happen unless the internal implementation of Properties::store changed
        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not escape property value");
    } catch (final IOException ex) {
        // This should never happen. IOException is only because the interface demands it
        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not escape property value", ex);
    }
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
final String escapedPath = escapePropertyValue("C:\\Users\\X");
writeToFile(escapedPath); // will pass "C\\:\\\\Users\\\\X"
```

This method a little bit expensive but, writing properties to a file is typically an sporadic operation anyway.

Answer (score -2):

I've been able to input values within the character ":

```
db_user="postgresql"
db_passwd="this,is,my,password"
```

Comment: Op says Java properties,  quotes don't work like that in java properties files.