# Java properties file specs

Tags: java, properties, specifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Escaping equal sign in properties files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406975/escaping-equal-sign-in-properties-files)

In a .properties file, can I use the character '=' after the first one?

Like this:

```
url=http://www.example.org/test=
```

Is it allowed and where can I know that it is allowed if it indeed is?

So far it seems to be working but I simply am not too sure it won't break later on.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406975/escaping-equal-sign-in-properties-files

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may put backslash escape character `(\)` before `=` and `:`.

Or better use the following code that prints out how your property should be *escaped*:

```
                Properties props = new Properties();
                props.setProperty("url", "http://www.example.org/test=");
                props.store(System.out, null);
```

Output:

```
#Wed Jan 12 14:30:39 GMT 2011
url=http\://www.example.org/test\=
```

Also, please check out [Java API information](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

Comment: This is NOT correct.  You don't need to escape your `=` and `:` characters, unless they're in the KEY of the property, instead of the VALUE.

Comment: Yes, as @DawoodibnKareem says, this is not correct. Only when the value starts with : you have to escape it otherwise \ is ignored

Comment: I wrote "you may put" not "you should". Besides that I pasted default behaviour of Java6 Properties store() method.

Answer (score 12):

Unless they change the spec of Properties, it will always work. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29 for the specs.