# Spring 3.0 @Value read from property file gettng exception on deployment

Tags: java, spring, properties

I am trying to build a spring 3.0 application version 3.1.0.RELEASE , where i want to read from a property file and using the @Value annotation read from it in my Component class. For this the changes i made:
in mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:mediamonitoring.properties"/>
```

Component class:

```
@Component
```

public class SomeHelper {

```
@Value("${baseUri}")
private String baseUri;

public String getBaseUri() {
    return baseUri;
}

public void setBaseUri(String baseUri) {
    this.baseUri = baseUri;
}
}
```

Property:

```
baseUri:http://localhost:8080/
```

and i have wired this helper class to a @service class using the @Autowired annotation.
When i build and deploy the application i get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'baseUri'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
```

Is there anything which i am missing because i just followed the standard proceedure.

Appreciate any help in advance.

-Vaibhav

Comment: Where is that property supposed to be defined?

Comment: in the file: mediamonitoring.properties

Comment: it seems file is not in class path. Furthermore, `:` can be used to assign. It was my fault.

Comment: it is in the classpath becoz if i give any other name of file instead of above it would throw filenotfound exception

Comment: i can see this file in WEB-INF/classes

Comment: Hawe you tried suggestions in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use `=` instead of `:` as separator

```
baseUri=http://localhost:8080/
```

Comment: Your file is not loaded (maybe not in classpath)

Comment: i can see this file in WEB-INF/classes

Comment: try without `classpath:` prefix as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779572/could-not-resolve-spring-property-placeholder?rq=1

Comment: removed classpath: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/mediamonitoring.properties]

Comment: Try move `<context:property-.../>` in same context of your `@Controller` as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275724/spring-3-0-5-doesnt-evaluate-value-annotation-from-properties?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

can't comment, need more rep, so using the asnwer option. check where did u put your mediamonitoring.properties. I mean, check if it's in your classpath

Comment: it is in the src/main/resources folder where the localization and related files are kept, also the file is getting recognized as when i renamed the file in context:property-placeholder location="classpath:mediamonitoring.properties" to some weired name it was throwing error file not found

Answer (score 0):

You should escape special characters `:` and `=` with `\` in value like this:

```
baseUri:http\://localhost\:8080/
```

Otherwise parser can't decide where you value ends and where new key starts.
See also [Java properties file specs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669805/java-properties-file-specs)

Comment: have you tried to change your key value to something else? `baseUri` could potentially clash with something.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `:` with `=` and use `#` instead of `$`

```
#{baseUri}
```

You can also try to use:

```
<util:properties id="props"
    location="classpath:/yourproperties.properties" />
```

And than:

```
@Value("#{props['yourProperty']}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are following the normal practices of having a `ContextLoaderListener` and a `DispatcherServlet` make sure that the `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:mediamonitoring.properties"/>` is in the correct application-context. It will only operate on beans in the same application-context, not on beans in a parent or child context.