# How to inject a key-value map with Spring 4?

Tags: java, spring, spring-4

```
VI=Visa
MC=Mastercard
...
```

Can I automatically inject this into a `Map<String, String>` with `Spring`?

Like:

```
@Resource("${myfile.properties}")
private Map<String, String> creditcards;
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Use `Property` instead of a map? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669805/java-properties-file-specs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28413642/1121883

Comment: Injecting list works, I've done it. Don't know about map, but a test with a springjunitrunner should give you an answer quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a nice feature:

```
@Bean(name = "credit")
public PropertiesFactoryBean mapper() {
    PropertiesFactoryBean bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("credit.properties"));
    return bean;
}
```

inject it anywhere as follows:

```
@Resource(name = "credit")
private Properties credit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you saw this:
[How to inject a Map using the @Value Spring Annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691949/how-to-inject-a-map-using-the-value-spring-annotation)

Here in the Question the person uses a map. So perhaps you can use this? Otherwise you can use the Properties class (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) and if you really need a map, you can transform the properties-object to a map