# Java Properties class implementation handles double/single quoted values?

Tags: java, properties, quotes

I want to support property file format like below (allow quotes surround the value):

```
key1=value1   
key2="value2"
key3='value'
```

My question is
does Java Properties class implementation handles double/single quoted values like above? I mean auto-removing quotes.

Actually I tried it's not, just want to confirm here. So I have to remove quotes myself.

EDIT:

I had a code below for my simple case:

```
String path = "/tmp/my.properties";
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(new FileInputStream(new File(path)));

String v = p.getProperty("key2");
if((v.startsWith("\"") && v.endsWith("\"")) || 
   (v.startsWith("\'") && v.endsWith("\'"))) {
    v = v.substring(1, v.length()-1);
}
```

Any recommendation on best practice to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406975/how-to-escape-the-equals-sign-in-properties-files

Comment: Good reference, but not exactly what I'm asking

Comment: I know I am late, but I use JDK 11 and the quotes are interpreted as part of the object, at least for me (for better or worse, I couldn't figure out what my bug was haha).

Answer (score 1):

To remove quotes, load the property file with your own extension of `ResourceBundle` which overrides `handleGetObject`.

See also:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html

Comment: My case is simple, just one property file. No resource bundle stuff