# Java Properties: how to escape # (hash)

Tags: java, properties, internationalization, escaping

How do I escape the hash sign (`#`) in Java properties files.

We have an internationalization framework that uses Java properties files.

There is a column called number and we want its header to be `#`. This ...

```
number=#
```

... doesn't work.

Comment: Since it is java, you need to replace hash(`#`) with `\\#` in your code. Notice the double slashes. Alternately you can replace `#` with `\\u0023`.

Answer (score 8):

This one should work without any escape character:

```
number=#
```

Just made a small test using code ....

```
prop.load(new FileInputStream ("./res/app.properties"));
System.out.println("Property: " +prop.getProperty("Number"));
```

... and property file (note upper/lower case):

```
Number=#
Text=test
```

Result:

```
Property: #
```

So rather check your spelling, lower/upper case or further processing.

Check out [this](http://fmpp.sourceforge.net/properties.html) or [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406975/how-to-escape-the-equals-sign-in-properties-files) (linking Java documentation too) for more.

**p.s.**: though it shouldn't be required you could also try the Unicode sequence: `\u0023`.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As the default escape character in Java is the `'\'` try to escape the hash with it.

Comment: Using *try* in an answer is a **bad practice**. You either *know* and answer with confidence, *or* post it as a comment or refrain from answering at all.

Comment: Well it's actually bad formulation. sorry for that.

Comment: Ironically this is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question when looking how to escape properly in the following case (DOES NOT WORK):

`zendesk.ticket.subject.prefix=#{{ticket.id}}`

In this case it needs escaping, otherwise the following exception occurs:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'createTicketService' defined in file [/Users/***]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 6; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'ticket' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 64 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'ticket' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1448)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1088)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 78 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'ticket' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:226)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:94)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:81)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:51)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:87)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:120)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.InlineList.getValueInternal(InlineList.java:95)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:297)
    at org.springframework.expression.common.CompositeStringExpression.getValue(CompositeStringExpression.java:105)
    at org.springframework.expression.common.CompositeStringExpression.getValue(CompositeStringExpression.java:42)
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:161)
    ... 83 common frames omitted
```

The / a solution would be to use `#{'#'}` the end result being (WORKS):

`zendesk.ticket.subject.prefix=#{'#'}{{ticket.id}}`

Answer (score 0):

Hash (`#`) is escaped with the `\` character in properties files. For example, to map key `#foo` to value `#bar`, you write:

```
\#foo=\#bar
```

It is applicable on both keys and values, although (as hinted in other answer) it is not strictly required for values.