# How to escape special characters in the key of properties file?

Tags: java, escaping, properties-file

I've got a `key = value` property in the .properties file:

```
give names: (1) code = xxx
```

... but when I tried to get that key, it threw an error:

> No message found under code give names: (1) code = xxx

I tried escaping the whitespace with `\` but it didn't work.

Do I need to escape `:`,`(`, and `)` characters as well?

Comment: Which class are you taking about?  Properties has no such error message.  If you get a stack trace, can you include it in your question?

Comment: Yes you need to escape : and space otherwise it's consider as the end of the key. Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29

Comment: If you want to programmatically escape the value for properties, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57983519/2411506

Answer (score 22):

You could check out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)

For info on how java interprets a properties file. The most relevant part is:

> The key contains all of the characters in the line starting with the first non-white space character and up to, but not including, the first unescaped '=', ':', or white space character other than a line terminator.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, two leading '\\' working fine for me.

For example : if your word contains the '$' character (e.g. Rf$RF, you can escape it with two leading '\\'