# How do I escape # character in value field in properties file

Tags: java, properties

I have a value in the properties file for a key as show below :

```
mykey = my#value
```

I have a trouble in reading the value after "`#`", I think it is treated as a comment.

I have tried using '`\`' to escape but it's not working.I have checked the previous post here and that was to escape space and : this is different as # is also used to represent comment,But I need # as a value.

Comment: yeah for property file #is used as comment. You can use any other character instead of #

Comment: This is NOT a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111403 - that question asks about special characters in the key, this is about escaping # in the value.

Comment: @ Anoop LL I can't it's a password and that is of third party system Which I do not have a control on so I can't use any other character

Comment: Try a unicode escape sequence `\u0023`

Comment: \\# is working thanks all