# Properties file escape a value

Tags: java, properties, escaping

I've looking through [How to escape the equals sign in properties files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406975/how-to-escape-the-equals-sign-in-properties-files) but didn't find my answer.

I have a `Java Properties File` that includes sets such as:

```
SOME_KEY = SOME_VALUE
```

This is normal. However, some of the values actually contain escape/control characters, such as URL's. This properties file is to be hand edited by a user on a rare occasion. I want the user to be able to simply paste in a URL and not worry about special rules, etc.

So I have this showing in my file now:

```
SOME_KEY = http://www.example.com/something.asp?some=
```

where `some=` is the base of dynamic URL where something after the `=` will cause the URL to respond differently.

From reading http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html it doesn't seem to make mention of needing to escape any escape/control characters after the first unescaped `=` or `:` is encountered, but I need/want to make sure.

I know that if my `KEY` had one of those characters present, then it would have to be escaped otherwise it'd be misread... such as:

```
SOME\=KEY = SOME_VALUE
```

Would make for a literal `SOME=KEY` as the key value.

In this above situation, excluding the obvious escaping of the `KEY`, is it necessary to hand-escape the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the first `=` without escape, no.

If you use eclipse, you might want install the [JBoss Tools Properties Editor](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Developer_Studio/4.0/html/Hibernate_Tools_Reference_Guide/properties_editor.html). You not need to worry about escaping values ​​manually as you mention `SOME=KEY`  or Unicode. However, the pluging escapes the characters to avoid reading and coding problems.

[image]

[image]

[image]

http://www.jboss.org/tools