# How to escape double column in Java properties file?

Tags: java, scala, properties-file, typesafe-config

I'm using

```
com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
// some time later 
params("myvar") = config.getString("myvar").trim
```

the value of the key is a wasb address. It does seem that `":"` does not work (as suggested by the error message), i.e.,

```
wasb":"//rest_of_the_path
```

What would be the escape character for `:`?

Comment: \: as suggested by javadoc :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406975/how-to-escape-the-equals-sign-in-properties-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the Properties API but [TypeSafe Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config).

You need to wrap that key into double-quotes. Quoting from [TypeSafe Config documentation](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/HOCON.md#unquoted-strings):

> Unquoted strings are used literally, they do not support any kind of escaping. Quoted strings may always be used as an alternative when you need to write a character that is not permitted in an unquoted string.

As such, you key needs to be `"wasb://rest_of_the_path"`