# unable to read Special Charecter like # from properties file in java

Tags: java

How to read Special Character # from Properties file in Java

password=Admin123#

when i read read password from properties file i am getting

password=Admin123

Comment: This is the comment character so everything following the `#` on the line will not appear if you use the Properties instance to read the file. See how to escape those

Comment: Thanks It Worked for me

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape special characters: [How to escape the equals sign in properties files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406975/how-to-escape-the-equals-sign-in-properties-files) see answer 4 exactly for your case:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33808156/3453727