# How to read property file with custom separator using Spring

Tags: spring, scala

I have a property file as below

```
Key1~~value1
Key2~~value2
```

How to read this custom separator property file using Spring.

Spring `@PropertySource` can read the property files with keys and values separated by `=` or `:`.

Comment: possible solution  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406975/how-to-escape-the-equals-sign-in-properties-files/33808156

Comment: that thread discusses about having the separator in keys or values. Also, the solution also is about having = or : as separator.

Answer (score 0):

On the presumption that you are using a created properties file. You can use the `setGlobalSeparator(String globalSeparator)` [method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/PropertiesConfigurationLayout.html#setGlobalSeparator-java.lang.String-) of `PropertiesConfigurationLayout` and change the separator to use `~~`. Per the documentation, it will overwrite the existing configuration layout to set the new global separator.

Something like this:

```
PropertiesConfiguration propertiesConfig = new PropertiesConfiguration("test.properties");
PropertiesConfigurationLayout layout = new PropertiesConfigurationLayout(propertiesConfig);
layout.setGlobalSeparator("~~");
propertiesConfig.setLayout(layout);
```

Comment: Using Spring as in? You are anyways using the `@PropertySource` annotation to get the properties file using Spring. You could use do this to set the default global separator.