# Spring Batch property placeholder endline

Tags: java, properties, spring-batch, separator

I am facing a problem while trying to store an end line separator in a java properties file in order to import it into an xml configuration file.

With the following xml :

```
<bean id="fooWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" value="file:${myJob.file.output}" />
    <property name="lineSeparator" value="${myJob.file.lineSeparator}" />
</bean>
```

The following property entry :

```
myJob.file.lineSeparator = &#10;
```

Gives : foo`&#10;`bar

---

```
myJob.file.lineSeparator = \n
```

Gives : foobar(Nothing)

---

```
myJob.file.lineSeparator = \\n
```

Gives : foo\nbar

---

```
myJob.file.lineSeparator = '\n' or "\n"
```

Gives :

```
foo' or foo"
'bar or "bar
```

it seems like it's working but the quotes remains.

---

Any solution to externalize the endline separator ?

Comment: did you try to work with escape characters? "\\n" ?

Comment: Thank for your response. Unfortunately, \\n results with \n in the file.

Comment: take a look into http://stackoverflow.com/a/29485923/62201, it works for me

Comment: with using jobparameters instead of propertyplaceholder it does work with "\\n", with properties file take a look in to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108103/can-the-key-in-a-java-property-include-a-blank-character

Comment: Thank you, Can you provide an example please? With a property entry in a .properties file.

Answer (score 0):

it does work for me with Spring 4 and

a properties file containing

```
lineSeparator=\n
```

spring configuration

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:META-INF/spring/my.properties"/>
```

spring batch configuration (removed file path config)

```
<bean id="itemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" scope="step" >
    <property name="lineSeparator" value="${lineSeparator}" />
</bean>
```